# solve system equations of integrals in python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, continuous-integration, integral

I need to solve system equations of integrals in python 3.2.

The equation that I need to solve: **update**

```
 integral_from_0_N of (x * f(x))  dx  =  constant  // here , constant > 0 , N > 0
```

where

```
f(x) = g(j,k) * (x/k)^(j-1) * exp(-x/k)   // here,  k > 0 , j > 0
```

Here,

```
g(j,k) = j / [ k* g1 (1+j, constant1/k)  - k* g1 (1+j, constant2/k)  + exp(-constant2/k)  * k^(1-j) * constant2^j  - exp(-constant1/k)  * k^(1-j) * constant1^j ]

constant1 >= 0 , constant 2 > 0
```

Where

```
     g1( p, q) = integral_from_q_to_inf of (t^(p-1) * exp(-t)) dt
```

I need to find solutions for k and j .  Here is the python code.

---

```
  from sympy import S, Eq, solve, integrals
  import sympy as sym
  import scipy.integrate as integ

  x, b, c, m, v, L, u = S('x, b, c, m, v, L, u'.split()) 
  equations = [Eq(m, integ.quad(xf(x, b, c), L, u))]

 def xf(x, b,c):
    return x*f(x,b,c)

 def f(x, b, c):
    return g(x, b,c) * (x/b)**(c-1) * sym.exp(-x/b)

 def g(x, b, c):
     c = 1+c  // TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
     L = 1 
     u = 10
     ff1 = b*g1(c, L/b)

 def g1(a,z):
   x = symbols('x')
   return sym.integrate(x**(a-1) * sym.exp(-2*x), (x,z, sym.oo))
```

I got error:

```
  quadpack.error: Supplied function does not return a valid float.
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: could you show the equations you are trying to solve as well?

Comment: Can you please add the full traceback exception?

Comment: My implementation may not be correct. So, traceback may not be helpful. Any suggestions about how to solve and implement the integral equations would be really appreciated. Thanks !